# Why i can not connect to expressjs from react when i use params method?

Tags: reactjs, express

**getSinglejs**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from "axios"



class GetSingle extends Component {
    state= {
        ids: [],
        title:"",
        content:"",
        id:""
    };
    getAllQuestions=()=>{
        axios.get(`api/question`)
            .then(res=>{
                this.setState({
                    ids:res.data.data
                })
            }).then(res1=>{
                this.setState({
                    title:this.state.ids[this.props.match.params.id].title,
                    content:this.state.ids[this.props.match.params.id].title,
                    id:this.state.ids[this.props.match.params.id]._id
                })
            })
            .catch(err=>{
                console.log(err)
            })
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getAllQuestions()
    }

    render() {

      //  console.log(this.props.match.params.id);
        //console.log(this.state.id);
       // console.log("taha")

        return (
            <div className={"container"}>
                <div className={"card"}>
                    <div className={"card-header"}>Questions</div>
                    <div className={"card-body"}>
                        <h3>{this.state.title}</h3>
                        <p>{this.state.content}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default GetSingle;
```

**Profilejs**

```
<div className={"card"}>
                            <div className="card-header">Your Questions</div>
                            {
                                this.state.questions.map((question,id)=>{
                                    return (
                                        <Link to={`/get/${id}`}  key={id} className="card-body">
                                            <h3>{question.title}</h3>
                                            <p>{question.content}</p>
                                        </Link>
                                    )
                                })
                            }

                        </div>
```

**app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter ,Route} from "react-router-dom"

import Navbar from "./React/Navi/Nav";
import Landing from "./React/components/Landing";
import Admin from "./React/components/Admin";
import GetSingle from "./React/components/GetSingle";

function App() {
    return (

            <div >
                <Navbar/>
                <Route exact path={"/land"} component={Landing}/>
                <Route path={"/register"} component={Register}/>
                <Route path={"/login"} component={Login}/>
                <Route path={"/profile"} component={Profile}/>
                <Route path={"/admin"} component={Admin}/>
                <Route path={"/get/:id"} component={GetSingle}/>
            </div>

    );
}

export default App;
```

**Error**

> *xhr.js:178 GET http://localhost:3000/get/api/question 404 (Not Found) 
>   react-dom.development.js:4168 GetSingle.js:27 Error: Request failed
>   with status code 404
>       at createError (createError.js:16)
>       at settle (settle.js:17)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:61)*

why am i getting this error? I tried a couple of ways to fix it but it didn`t work. How can i use params method correctly?

Comment: are you able to get questions via postman on this link `http://localhost:3000/get/api/question` ?

Comment: actually that is the proplem ,"get" automoticaly occurs there it shouldt be http://localhost:3000/api/question , İt  because i use get/:id  ,the other Routes above that they works normally.

Comment: try this : `axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/question')` , always store your base API URL in env file and use it from there like  `axios.get('${base_url}api/question')`